# Division operation for decimal value is not working

Tags: php, division, integer-division

I have one scenario, in which I have to calculate Tax. For that, I am using some addition, subtraction and division operation.

Note ** I am running on PHP 5.6.17

But I have one situation in which I have to divide integer value with the decimal value.
for example ( 1,047/1.077 ), and this division operation is not working.

How do I achieve this in an older version of PHP

Comment: Do not mix dot and comma.

Comment: `1,047` is an invalid number

Comment: computer don't understand thousand like this (1,047), Remove the comma from your number and give it a try again

Comment: Ohh yes, Thank You all ... I didn't notice that ... after removing comma it is working.

Comment: Then, enable error reporting, that's a syntax error